# Отменить адаптивность JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, есть адаптивный сайт, возник вопрос как правильно реализовать переход на основную версию сайта для мобильных устройств. Ведь для мобильного девайса все адаптируется через media классы и сам bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, чтобы переключаться с мобильной версии на полную и обратно, нужно, чтобы были эти две отдельные версии - мобильная и полная. Адаптивный сайт - это одна версия, которая просто на разных экранах по-разному отображается.

Но можно подставить "костыль" - по клику менять содержимое мета-тега viewport (а именно - с initial-scale=1 на initial-scale=0 и обратно):

```
<button id="full">Полная версия</button>
<button id="mobile">Мобильная версия</button>
<script>
    $('#full').click(function(){
        $('[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0, user-scalable=no');
    });
    $('#mobile').click(function(){
        $('[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Соглашусь это костыль.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью javascript можно зафиксировать ширину сайта (если bootstrap то ширину контейнера) например на 1200 px

Пример с использованием jQuery:

```
$(".container").css("width",1200);
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/234228)

Comment: @Sublihim, А какой должен был быть ответ? Не всегда нужно приводить код если речь идет о элементарных вещах. Вопрос пользователя я понял, мне ничего не нужно уточнять, и думаю он понял мой ответ.

Comment: помимо топикстартера, сюда приходят люди за поиском овтета. Дополните ответ хотя бы примером кода, что ли. Дайте более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Единственно что в данном случае можно сделать, это играть со значениями вьюпорта:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```